# ERROR Invariant Violation: "bahikhata" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run my app locally since yesterday, but every time I run it I get these two errors

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\bahikhata\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\5j485q3x\obj\arm64-v8a\libreanimated.so.tmp59ab838'
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\bahikhata\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\watchers\NodeWatcher.js:231:14 {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'C:\Users\abhij\OneDrive\Desktop\bahikhata\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\5j485q3x\obj\arm64-v8a\libreanimated.so.tmp59ab838'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

```
 ERROR  Error: Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN8facebook5react19ReadableNativeArrayC1EN5folly7dynamicE" referenced by "/data/app/~~P2jmaGYkHGGLBunzznA3AQ==/com.bahikhata-ExUQoctirNf2zbU764o_Kw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libreanimated.so"..., js engine: hermes
 LOG  Running "bahikhata" with {"rootTag":11}
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "bahikhata" has not been registered. This can happen if:
Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: herme
```

I tried both things.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm i

cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build
```

(no error comes here, Build Successfully run)